# 18.0.4 LTS boots on older Macs, not on newer

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS on a microSD card so I can run it on my Macs (but also on any recent laptop that might normally be running Windows). I want to be able to transfer files easily between Ubuntu and MacOS or WIndows boxes if I plug the card into them, so I create the following partition table with a FAT32 partition -

> Part 1: +1G VFAT            (0700)
>
> Part 2: +1M BIOSBOOT        (ef02)  -- this is just in case someone has a machine that uses BIOS boot
>
> Part 3: +250M EFI           (ef00)
>
> Part 4: +13500M /           (8300)
>
> Part 5: +15000M /mnt/data   (8300)

I have booted from a live USB stick and chosen to install Ubuntu onto my SDCard, and all seems to go well - if I put the SDCard into a USB3 adapter, then plug that into my 2009 Mac Pro, or my 2009 MacBook Pro I can boot up into a "proper" Ubuntu (i.e. not a live distribution).

However, if I put the USB adapter into my 2015 MacBook Pro, or put the SDCard directly into the SDCard slot, when I boot all I get is the black screen message "Grub error minimal bash like line editing is supported", with the options attached o that message.

I've tried the fix given on http://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/ but this does not result in a bootable device.

If I try the install in which I let the Ubuntu Live distro write new partitions etc onto the SDcard (i.e. wipe everything on it), I get two partitions on the SDcard - again, it doesn't boot on the 2015 Macbook, but if I install and run boot-repair I can then boot the card on all three of my Macs. Boot-repair doesn't help with my 5-partition scheme version - it ends with an error.

BTW, I can install Fedora onto the SDCard using Fedoramediawriter-osx-4.1.1-rebuilt and it runs fine on my newer Macbook and the Mac Pro, and boots on the old Macbook but continually reboots :-(

So - what should I try next to get 18.0.4 LTS up and running on my newer hardware?